# Two packages have the same class name inside the same namespace. How to specifically use each class?

Tags: c#, .net

The `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` (v3.29.1.0) and `Micosoft.Azure.Documents` (v2.10.3.0) has the same class called `UnixDateTimeConverter` within the same namespace `Microsoft.Azure.Documents`. My project needs to use both packages, and I cannot rename both. How can I specifically use the class of `Microsoft.Azure.Documents` package? ( cause that of `Micosoft.Azure.Documents` has `public` access modifier which can be called anywhere)

[Micosoft.Azure.Cosmos package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ylYV.png)

[Micosoft.Azure.Documents package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GfV6.png)

**Update:Specifying the problem occurs in a CosmosModel/Student.cs file**

```
namespace DataAccess.CosmosModel{
public class Student{
public string id { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public bool IsEmailConfirmed { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
public string CountryCode { get; set; }

[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(Microsoft.Azure.Documents.UnixDateTimeConverter))]
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_ts")]
 public virtual DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
```

Comment: you cannot use the one that is internal since you would not have access to it. you can only use the public one.

Comment: yes but it has the same namespace, how can I use the public one as it also reference to the internal one @JonathanAlfaro

Comment: One idea albeit extreme.  You can create a separate dll with a reference to only one package in that class library project.  Do the code that uses that class in there like "utilities"

Comment: [Aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias)

Comment: they are not in same namespace

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think extern alias is a good way to deal with this, but I'm stuck at adding aliases to Nuget package references. I got CS043 error and do not know or understand the way to fix it [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0430?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0430))

Comment: there is implementation in the old cosmos client and also one in newtonsoft but see answer below of how to specify which one to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the key is that they are not in same namespace and you can choose which one you would like to use in your using section of code for instance

```
using UnixDateTimeConverter = Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.UnixDateTimeConverter;
```

this would instruct to use this implementation and not the older, but it is typically only necessary when you are using both namespaces to begin with, so just as often we can remove one of the using statements.

Update 1 (one more to follow):
When issue is to serialize to and from Azure Cosmos, you can choose to let the driver handle your conversion

```
[BsonDateTimeOptions]
public DateTime UpdatedUTCZero { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Details about Serialization on the .net driver can be found here:
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/apidocs/html/R_Project_CSharpDriverDocs.htm

so there is a huge capability from the mongo driver:
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/apidocs/html/N_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization.htm

Update 2:
Wanting to elaborate, i'm sure you can find a hook to completely replace serialization, but if you want to use the mongo driver to for instance support 'schema' changes with the ExtraElements and such things i recommend looking in to, you're left with a collection interface IMongoCollection so if not using the Bson Serializer you'd have to store payload as string, which is sort of not good for querying.

However if You implement the serializing methods from link above, you can totally Use newtonsoft for serializing, just remember to tag your id with [BsonId] or it will generate one for You

Update 3: Example using the MongoDb.Driver and MongoDb.Json
I wouldn't normally interfere with the internal timestamp a.k.a _ts though i do not see why You couldn't expose it, it like the _id field relates to the MongoDb engine used to interface with cosmos. Wouldn't put virtual on, it's a .net thing not Bson/ Json.

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

// ...
public class Student{
  [BsonId]
  public string Id { get; set; }
  [BsonDateTimeOptions]
  public DateTime LastUpdatedDateTime{ get; set;}    
  [BsonElement("ts")] 
  public BsonTimestamp TimeStamp{ get; set; }  
  // ...
}
```

See section on timestamps: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/bson-types/
Also found a good article about dealing with mongo db engine related time issues: http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/6c715186-97b1-427a-9ccc-deb3ece7b839.aspx this field has quite a few options.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work as my project need to reference to both packages, and if you look closer at the 2 links to 2 pics, you can see that they both have the same namespace, which makes it impossible to use `using alias directive`

Comment: You will get the `UnixDateTimeConverter` not exist in the namespace `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` compiled error

Comment: @DatHa not if the asker is correct to say that that namespace actually contain said class. If I understand correct is is the question how do I specify which implementation I want.
I will agree that in my version 3.20 of Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos there is no such converter

Comment: yeah sadly the namespace contains the `UnixDateTimeConverter` class and the package name is not the same for both packages.

Comment: @DatHa so with cosmos, we have the old version when they called it document (db) and the new where they use their branded name (cosmos) - these generations of the code are not intended to work together in the same solution. the intend is that You upgrade your package and then microsoft.azure.documents will no longer be referenced and you will not have access to the internal unix handling.
Could the real question be why you would want that and can you change this requirement?

Comment: yes I think I have asked the wrong question, and yours are correct. because I have to re-written the project from .NET 4.7.1 to .NET 6 with all the dependencies update to the latest. But I had mistakenly installed both of them. I think my question now is "How to get the type of `UnixDateTimeConverter` despite of its protection level?"

Comment: Here are the lines that is needed:
`[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(Microsoft.Azure.Documents.UnixDateTimeConverter))]
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_ts")]
[JsonIgnore]
public DateTime? Timestamp { get; set; }`

Comment: Nice one, well fought :)

Comment: I think I am going to replace the `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.UnixDateTimeConverter` to `Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.UnixDateTimeConverter`. Is it still OK? @T.Nielsen

Comment: Depending on Your interface, if You use mongo interface towards cosmos, You can also choose to just use datetime and have the engine do the conversions, it will then store it in the epoc/ unix format, but you will get it back in ISO8601 'utc' time corrected format, persisted without you needing to care.

Seems like you're trying to control the serialization but you could just bind the type model you're using directly and have an attribute notation mind the serialization for You, ill update with alternatives to control serializer also @datha

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. I will definitely try it when using MongoDB. Unfortunately, my current project data mapping mainly occurs between MSSQL Database and CosmosDB. My only solution right now to move on ( although it is really bad practice) is to write a custom class that extends the `DataTimeConverterBase` ( the supper class of `UnixDateTimeConverter`) and copy all the codes in the library to make it work :(((((

Comment: I have added a little code to specify the problem @T.Nielsen

Comment: @DatHa i updated with what you can choose to do using the .net driver for mongodb in its own right, is there any reason you have to use Newtonsoft for serialization, i suspect although brilliant at serializing it is not an expert on Bson which is what the mongo engine on top of cosmos understands.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @T.Nielsen The Newtonsoft is widely used in my project and it works just fine so our team decides to keep it. By the way I am still a newcomer to stackoverflow, hence I do not have enough star to vote for your answer. I will get back when I am able to do so

Comment: @DatHa I am glad that You've found a way through. if you are satisfied with an answer that You have asked Yourself, You can accept the answer, there is a button. You do not have to upvote when you ask yourself. Details: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers